# How to use vectorized function to check across columns in data frame

Tags: r, sapply

I want to check the relationship in pairs of columns in a data frame, eg. if there are 'AB's are existed in the even column (2nd),then I replace the observations in the odd column(1st) with this certain value in the even column. If I want to do the same manipulation across multiple pairs of columns(1st vs. 2nd, 3rd vs. 4th and etc), I can do it manually as what I have written down below, but if I have 10 pairs of columns like this, how I can do that in an efficient manner, for example use `sapply`?

```
##generate demo data
data<-data.frame(a<-c(1:5),
b<-c(1,2,'AC','ABAB',4),
c<-c(2:6),
d<-c(2,3,5,'BC','AB')
,stringsAsFactors = F)
data[,c(1,3)]<-sapply(data[,c(1,3)],as.character)
names(data)<-letters[1:4]
str(data)

##manual version
indx<-!grepl('[^AB]', data$c)
data$a[indx]<-data$c[indx]

indx<-!grepl('[^AB]', data$d)
data$b[indx]<-data$d[indx]
data

#   a    b c  d
# 1 1    1 2  2
# 2 2    2 3  3
# 3 3   AC 4  5
# 4 4 ABAB 5 BC
# 5 5   AB 6 AB
```

Comment: Seems `data[, 1:2] <- data[, 3:4]` should do it..?

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639040/in-r-compare-one-column-value-to-all-other-columns

Comment: how about using identical function to check if the two columns are identical

Comment: `x1[x1 != x2] <- x2[x1 != x2]` is the same as `x1 <- x2` (assuming the vectors have the same length, class and other attributes). It is not clear what you mean by a more complicated example.

Comment: @Frank agreed - ifelse is a function, but I was just showing how to put that code into a function. Deleted my answer as I am not sure anymore what the question actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `Map` function if you know before hand the mapping between columns, i.e. in this case I assume column 1 paired with column 3, column 2 paired with column 4:

```
data[1:2] = Map(function(x, y) ifelse(!grepl("[^AB]", y), y, x), data[1:2], data[3:4])

data
#  a    b c  d
#1 1    1 2  2
#2 2    2 3  3
#3 3   AC 4  5
#4 4 ABAB 5 BC
#5 5   AB 6 AB
```

Comment: Cool, so for this example, the Map is equivalent to mapply?

Comment: It is. `Map` is equivalent to `mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)`.